# regex find any string that starts with @ and ends with either space, =, ; or newline

Tags: c#, regex

This is my final question about regex, hopefully for the rest of my life.  I would like to return any string within a larger block of text that meets the stated requirement above.

Begins with `@` and ends with either , `;`, `=`, or a newline `\n`.

I tried the following with no luck:

```
return @"(^@).*?(?=\s|;|\=|\r|\n)";
```

My purpose is to try and extract the variable @tmp from a string that looks like this.  (TSQL statement) so that it can be highlighted in a richtext box.

```
declare @tmp varchar(25);
set @tmp='test';
select * from mytable where mycolumn = @tmp;
```

I am expanding the capabilities of an existing editor but it was missing the ability to highlight variables.  (only keywords, comments, literals etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the rules of SQL Server variables, this regex should work better than the above:

```
@[\w\d_@$]+
```

Because there is *any* number of character that can terminate a variable name, not just the ones that you listed. So this expression will look for anything that is valid instead, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962(v=sql.80).aspx

EDIT: Sorry, forgot about the "\d" in there. Digits are valid too after all.

Comment: Updated: I copied the wrong version of the expression. It was missing the "\d" class: digits are valid in varaibles too. i.e. "@0" is a totally valid name.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick `@[^\s=;\n]+(?=[\s=;\n])`

Here's an example of the pattern matching your test string: http://regexr.com?3445h

Answer (score 1):

The regex you want is:

```
new Regex(@"@.*?[ ;=\n]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
(@.+?)[ |=|;|\n]
```